# swift. UserDefaults and UISwitch

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I'm trying to get UserDefaults to work with a UISwitch, but the switch state is not saving when I force close the app and reopen it.

Update: Got it to work. The switch state will stay in either the "on" or "off" state even when the app is closed.

My code:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


@IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "saveTrue")
    defaults.set(false, forKey: "saveFalse")

    if sender.isOn == false {
        sender.setOn(defaults.bool(forKey: "saveFalse"), animated: true)
    } else if sender.isOn == true {
        sender.setOn(defaults.bool(forKey: "saveTrue"), animated: true)
    }

}
```

ANSWER:;;;

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let switchValue = getSwitchValue(), switchValue {
        switchOutlet.setOn(true, animated: true)
    } else {
        switchOutlet.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
}


@IBAction func Switch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
if sender.isOn == false {
        setSwitchStatus(status: false)
        sender.setOn(false, animated: true)
    } else if sender.isOn == true {
        setSwitchStatus(status: true)
        sender.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
}


func setSwitchStatus(status: Bool?) {
    if status != nil {
        defaults.set(status, forKey: "save1")
    }
}

func getSwitchValue() -> Bool? {
    return defaults.bool(forKey: "save1")
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Your `sender.setOn` code does not change anything. You are setting `setOn = false` when it is already `false`.

Comment: Off topic but instead of comparing to true and false you can just do `if sender.isOn {...} else {...}` or use a ternary operator

Comment: I used the .isOn to set true or false. The .setOn is to have the switch in either the ON or OFF state. My goal is to have the state of the UISwitch in memory using UserDrfaults. SO if the app is closed while the UISwitch is in the On state, it will stay that way when the app is reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but I'd do it like this:

```swift
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
@IBOutlet mySwitch: UISwitch!

//or any other function that is called 'when the app is reopened' 
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.mySwitch.setOn(defaults.bool(forKey: "switchDefaultsKey"), animated: true)
}

@IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchDefaultsKey")
}
```

Comment: I got the issues resolved. Stated it in the initial question body. Also in the viewDidAppear func,  "defaults.setOn" will not work